# :empty selector not working in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

i used `:empty` selector in  `.error` class. the problem is that even when there is no content inside the div with class of error, the error class is not removed completely. 
when i tested in firebug, i found that the div still has some whitespace and when i remove that extra spaces, the div then disappears.

```
.error{ border:solid 1px #ff0000; color:#ff0000;}
.error:empty{ display:none;}
```

the div shows like this on debugging:

```
<div class="error">     </div>
```

that extra spaces you see is the problem.
Is there any way i can show `&nbsp;` in css to display:none ? pls help.

Comment: Do you have any control over the output?

Answer (score 25):

it is because `<div class="error">     </div>`([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BF73Z/1/)) is not empty, it has a text node as the child.

[:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty)

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at
>   all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are
>   considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether
>   an element is considered empty or not.

Try

```
<div class="error"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BF73Z/)

Comment: I think that's precisely the problem though, I don't think the OP has control over the HTML output.

Answer (score 5):

If you have only specific elements as childs you could try:

```css
.error:not(:has(yourChildElements)) {
   display: none
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class **doesn't select** elements, containing **elements or text** (and white space **is text**).

However, there is now the **experimental** [`:blank`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank) pseudo-class which **selects** elements, containing **nothing or just white space**, and `.error:blank` would select that `<div>` element. You should **avoid** using **experimental** features in your **production** code, though.

Comment: People should keep in mind that `:blank` is not supported on most browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_blank

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec I believe he mentionned that `:blank` is *experimental*, so I don't see any reason to downvote him?

Comment: @AdnaneAr yes. It was to add the link caniuse that I submitted this comment. I did not downvoted him.